# How to clear a cell if there is no data in it

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex

How to clear a cell if there is no data in it?

```
=ArrayFormula(REPLACE(IMPORTRANGE("1I1MK51uYT_WJDh0fiiHxLjnYMoQOVoZi41XnHM", "SetstudentMatrik!C2:C"),1,6,"******"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `REGEXREPLACE` function in your formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(REPLACE(IMPORTRANGE("1I1MK51uYT_WJDh0fiiHxLjnYMoQOVoZi41XnHM", "SetstudentMatrik!C2:C"),1,6,"******"),"******",""))
```

If you want to keep the leading `******` use the following formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(REPLACE(IMPORTRANGE("1I1MK51uYT_WJDh0fiiHxLjnYMoQOVoZi41XnHM", "SetstudentMatrik!C2:C"),1,6,"******"),"******$",""))
```

Please read more about **[`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)**

Answer (score 0):

## REGEXREPLACE

If going this route, I'd dispense with the REPLACE function given:

1. It seems redundant since REGEXREPLACE can already replace values.
2. The code without spaces requires 80 less characters (62 vs. 142)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   REGEXREPLACE(
     ""& [array/range], ".{6}(.+)", "******"& "$1"))
```

**Using your Data:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   REGEXREPLACE(
     ""& IMPORTRANGE("1I1MK51uYT_WJDh0fiiHxLjnYMoQOVoZi41XnHM",
        "SetstudentMatrik!C2:C"), ".{6}(.+)", "******"& "$1"))
```

1. Prepending an empty text string **`""`** to the values ensures they are interpreted as strings in case they are formatted otherwise.  This approach was used because it requires 3 characters **`""&`** vs. 9 for **`TOTEXT()`**
2. REGEXREPLACE performs the search and replacement:

   1. Its regular expression captures a non-zero number of characters (greedy), **`(.+)`**, that follow exactly 6 of any character(s), **`.{6}`**.
   2. The capture group **`$1`** is replaced by a string made up of **`"******"`** prepended to the capture group
   3. If the capture group is not matched, no replacement is performed.

## TOCOL Approach

Removes blank cells from **`C2:C`** using TOCOL before performing the replacement. Relies on contiguous data rows (no gaps) or rows will be offset.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   REPLACE(TOCOL(
     IMPORTRANGE("1I1MK51uYT_WJDh0fiiHxLjnYMoQOVoZi41XnHM",
       "SetstudentMatrik!C2:C"),1), 1, 6, "******")))
```